# Custom config files in an EE addon

Tags: add-on-development, module, extension, config

I moved a custom addon out of system/third_party into a third_party folder above web root

all was well until I realized that the addon didn't account for a different third_party folder location

I updated the paths but now I'm having some strange issues with EE not loading custom config files

I'm loading the these files in the constructor of the mcp file.

```
$this->_EE->load->add_package_path(PATH_THIRD . 'custom_addon/');
$this->_EE->load->config('custom_addon');
```

the config files seem to load fine (I don't get any errors) but I can't access the config items in the file

```
$this->_EE->config->item('some_value');
```

doesn't return anything

any idea what's up?

EE2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used load->config but all the other load commands allow for a second parameter:

```
$this->EE->load->model('filterdb_model', "filterDB");
$modules = $this->EE->filterDB->get_installed_modules($moduleName);
```

So the second parameter is the reference to the class. But reading the CI documentation for config doesn't seem to behave the same - it expects a boolean :(

Personally I just do this:

```
require PATH_THIRD.strtolower(get_class($this)).'/config/config.php';
$this->name = $config['name'];
$this->version = $config['version'];
```

[CI Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html)

[Forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/166742/#798282)

[Another CI reference](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/192728/#909814)